# updating my page to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I needed to update this to jQuery and i think i got everything but it isnt working, the only thing i can think of is the doc.body.style.back sections arent right but i dont know the proper format for jQuery. Can anyone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let clicker = $('#jeffery');
    clicker.on('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e) {
    document.body.style.background = 'url("jefferyBig.jpg")';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    let clicker1 = $('#eagles');
    clicker1.on('click', clickHandler1);

function clickHandler1(e) {
    document.body.style.background = 'url("eaglesBig.jpg")';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    let clicker2 = $('#wentz');
    clicker2.on('click', clickHandler2);

function clickHandler2(e) {
    document.body.style.background = 'url("wentzBig.jpg")';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    let clicker3 = $('#jenkins');
    clicker3.on('click', clickHandler3);

function clickHandler3(e) {
    document.body.style.background = 'url("jenkinsBig.jpg")';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    let clicker4 = $('#cox');
    clicker4.on('click', clickHandler4);

function clickHandler4(e) {
    document.body.style.background = 'url("coxBig.jpg")';
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to add an image in the backgroound

Comment: you shouldn't have multiple .ready() functions. just put everything in one

Comment: @Cruiser While that is more organized, there is nothing inherently wrong with multiple .ready() functions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, agreed.

Comment: you only need to call `(document).ready()` one time, and wrap all your code inside of it. Also you don't need to assign the selectors to variables you can just call `$('#jenkins').click(function())`. Of course the way you're doing it is fine but you should strive to write more terse code

Comment: This code example is ripe for refactoring

Comment: @ScottMarcus it is inherently problematic though, multiple ready() functions make the code more difficult to read and therefore more difficult to maintain. While technically correct, I don't think it is best practice at all

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Agreed. My comment was based on Cruiser's comment, which reads like multiple .ready() calls are incorrect, which they are not.

Comment: Ah I see, apologies I misunderstood @ScottMarcus

Answer (score 2):

You use the **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method:

```
$(body).css("background", "url('eaglesBig.jpg')");
```

And, as others have pointed out, you don't need multiple `document.ready()` functions - you can combine all the code you want to run as soon as the DOM is ready into one .ready() function. Also, your current code doesn't have all the necessary `}` syntax, so check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg)');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `css()` method to update the background image. You can also make the code DRY by placing the image src in a `data-*` attribute on the element to click. Then you can group all the required elements with a class and have a single event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bg-trigger').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', `url("${$(this).data('src')}")`);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="bg-trigger" data-src="jefferyBig.jpg">Jeffery</div>
<div class="bg-trigger" data-src="eaglesBig.jpg">Eagles</div>
<div class="bg-trigger" data-src="wentzBig.jpg">Wentz</div>
<div class="bg-trigger" data-src="jenkinsBig.jpg">Jenkins</div>
<div class="bg-trigger" data-src="coxBig.jpg">Cox</div>
```

The advantages of this method is that the JS code is simplified, and also it's infinitely extensible without having to touch the JS code. To add options, you just create new HTML elements with the appropriate `class` and `data` attributes.